# How to get first number from a string with example

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have text that looks like this:

> Owen White punt for 26 yards, downed at the army 37

I want to get the punt length from this expression, in this case 26 yards. How could i do this?

To answer some questions: I have about 800 of these sentences, and I want to fill a list with the amount of yards( in this case, 26) So I cannot add both values to a list, only the first.

Comment: Did you think of using regular expressions to search for matching number patterns?
If you need to avoid regular expressions, then you can split the string by spaces, iterate over each word, and try converting the word to an int within a `try` block.

Comment: how structured is the typical input?

Comment: Is it a basic form for all sentence?

Comment: I don't know python, or I would give you an exact answer. But what you're asking for is standard stuff, it can be done with regex somehow, or some built-in method like findFirst(pattern)

Answer (score 2):

You can use regex as below:

```
import re
str = "Owen White punt for 26 yards, downed at the army 37"
#search using regex
x = re.findall('[0-9]+', str)
print(x[0])
```

Comment: except: he only wants the first numbers, and this will include the "37".

Comment: No, it's printing first number. Please look carefully:)

Comment: You can use `x = re.search('[0-9]+', str)` and then `print(x.group())`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get 26 from `'foo123 has 26 bars'`, then:

```py
val = [int(v) for v in s.split() if v.isnumeric()][0]
```

But if you want to get 123 instead, then:

```py
val = int(re.search(r'\d+', s).group())
```

Comment: I like this. Very Clean <3

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
sentence = 'Owen White punt for 26 yards, downed at the army 37'
first_digit_in_sentence = ''
words = sentence.split(' ')

for word in words:
    if word.isdigit():
        first_digit_in_sentence = word
        break;

print(first_digit_in_sentence)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using regex. There are plenty of tools that can help you create match patterns for capturing specific characters in strings as well as rules for what to capture.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string '26 yards' as a result, and the format of your input string is always '[digit] yards' then you could use this piece of code which uses regular expression and prints a list with every match of '[digit] yards' from `my_string`:

```
import re
my_string = 'Owen White punt for 26 yards, downed at the army 37'
regex_pattern = r'\d+ yards'
result = re.findall(regex_pattern, my_string)
print(result)
```

The first `r` in the regex pattern specifies that it is a raw string, it means it is stored as it appears. For example, '' is just a backslash instead of an escaping.
Then the regex pattern starts: `\d` means it looks for digits, `*` means 1 or more of the preceding token, so in this case one or more digits. Then  `yards`, which is just the string as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved a similar problem in the past. If you know that the number you are looking for is in a specific position in the string (you know that it will be the first or second). Try it (without regex) like this:

```
a_string = "Owen White punt for 26 yards, downed at the army 37"
result = []
for word in a_string.split():
    if word.isdigit():
        result.append(int(word))

print(result[0]) #Output: 26
```